# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.rallydev.webservice.v1_28.domain.OperationResult - Object

Tags: apache-axis, rally

I've built an integration with Rally using the SOAP API so that when I target a bug in bugzilla, a user story is created and scheduled in the proper release. It also work in update, so if I just update the target the US will be associated to the specified release in Rally.

It has been working for a while, but now it seems not to work anymore.

I get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.rallydev.webservice.v1_28.domain.OperationResult - Object
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.onStartChild(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.rallydev.webservice.v1_28.service.RallyServiceSoapBindingStub.update(RallyServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1166)
```

I updated to the latest API, but not luck.

Answer (score 1):

Stefano,

This is a known issue in Rally and we expect it will be corrected this Saturday (3Dec11). If you need to get the code running right away, you can catch the thrown exception by editing the generated code.

As long as the SAX exception is caught, it does not prevent updates from actually succeeding. A couple customers have been able to workaround the mismatched return value by wrapping the update code and/or calls to the Rally service in a try/catch block similar to an example here on a Task:

```
try { 
    OperationResult operationResult = rallyService.update(myTask);
} catch (Exception e) { 
    System.out.println("Rally SAX Exception encountered"); 
}
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.

- Mark

Comment: Thanks Mark! Will I need to download a new wsdl and rebuild?

Comment: You will need to rebuild your wsdl.